# How should I cross-reference items in an enumerated list?

Tags: cross-referencing

When cross-referencing an item in an enumerated list, should one use `\ref` or `\eqref`? For instance, suppose I have a theorem spread across two points, like below.

> **Theorem 4.3** Let *x*, *y* and *z* be real numbers. Then
>
> (i) *x + y = y + x*;
>
> (ii) *(x + y) + z = x + (y + z)*.

Then should I refer to `Theorem 4.3.i` or `Theorem 4.3.(i)`?

Comment: I'd probably use 4.3(i) noextra dot as there is none in the theorem. Also, use enumitem for a better enumerate, then ref will carry whatever formatting you give the label, so no need for eqref (which are semantically wrong for items anyway)

Comment: `eqred` is pointless here, since you have no  numbered equation.

Comment: Please lift the "primarily opinion-based" hold on this posting. The OP's posting actually contains two separate questions. The narrow question, "should one write  Theorem 4.3.i or Theorem 4.3.(i)?", is indeed mostly based on personal preferences. But there's also a much broader question contained in this posting. The broader question is "how do I create cross-references in a flexible and general manner, so that I can change the display format easily for the whole document with minimal additional effort?" I believe it's worth answering the broader question.